# SQL - Multiple Table Sums

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that is far out of my wheel house.  Hoping someone may have a solution here.  Below is what I am trying to get to,

Tables

- `MemberInfo` contains (MemberID, MemberName, Address, Phone, Email, etc for 150 members)
- `MemberID` which has each members unique vendor IDs, so it contains (MemberID, VendorA_MemberID, VendorB_MemberID, VendorC_MemberID ....for 20 vendors)
- `VendorA` contains (VendorA_MemberID, TranDate, TranAmount, Category etc..)
- Repeat for all vendor tables

I will be using MemberID from the MemberInfo table as  the variable on the user interface side.

The report I need to return would have a summary of transaction amount by Vendor by quarter with an annual summary.  I can write this query for one vendor using member as a variable with out issue.  Its when I have to return all vendors in a single query I am at a loss.  Additionally there are NULL values where some members do not carry a particular vendor.

The returned query in my mind would be as followed with headers,

```
- |VendorA | Q1 Sum | Q2 Sum | Q3 Sum | Q4 Sum | YTD Sum |
- |VendorB | Q1 Sum | Q2 Sum | Q3 Sum | Q4 Sum | YTD Sum |
- |VendorC | Q1 Sum | Q2 Sum | Q3 Sum | Q4 Sum | YTD Sum |
- |VendorD | Q1 Sum | Q2 Sum | Q3 Sum | Q4 Sum | YTD Sum |
```

I hope this was clearly communicated and is possible.
Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: To expand on the comment from @TomH. You are struggling to write what seems like a simple query here because your tables are not normalized. As a result you have to write unbelievably complicated sql for what should be a simple aggregate. You have repeating columns and entire tables for what should be a single column. You don't need help with the query, you need help designing a better architecture.

Comment: I do not disagree, unfortunately this is clean up of an existing system and my organization is so small we do not have the funds to hire or contract out the process.  Just trying to get buy with what we have...Looks like I will be working weekends to get everything consolidated.